# Using dir to find all subfolders with a given name

Tags: windows, batch

I was expecting `dir build /S /b /A:D` to find all folders in all sub-folder of the current folder that are called `build`. However not so.

```
C:\GoogleDrive>dir build /S /B /A:D

C:\GoogleDrive>dir *build /S /B /A:D
C:\GoogleDrive\build
C:\GoogleDrive\app\build

C:\GoogleDrive>
```

The first command, `dir build /S /B /A:D` is executed in `C:\GoogleDrive` and finds nothing.

However, the second command, `dir *build /S /B /A:D` does find the two subfolders `C:\GoogleDrive\build` and `C:\GoogleDrive\app\build`.

How could I find all such folders?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dir build /s /AD /B
```

I've just created a test structure and it works.  Interestingly, if there is a gap between the /A and D you get a final 'File not found'.

One comment - the tag is ms-dos, but your dir name is more than 8 characters so you obviously aren't using dos.  What version of windows is this on?

Answer (score 0):

win10.

This counter-example works on two different win10 machines:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 24E7-CD8C

 Directory of C:\test

29/05/2020  19:57    <DIR>          .
29/05/2020  19:57    <DIR>          ..
29/05/2020  19:54    <DIR>          build
23/05/2020  14:26               878 text.txt
               1 File(s)            878 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   4,363,292,672 bytes free

C:\test>dir text.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 24E7-CD8C

 Directory of C:\test

23/05/2020  14:26               878 text.txt
               1 File(s)            878 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   4,363,280,384 bytes free

C:\test>dir build
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 24E7-CD8C

 Directory of C:\test\build

29/05/2020  19:54    <DIR>          .
29/05/2020  19:54    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   4,363,214,848 bytes free

C:\test>
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion using a `for` loop that works on any window

```
for /r /d %i in (*)do echo\"%i"|find /i "build"
```